# Platform-agnostic web framework in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am looking for framework, that has some basic framework tools like routing, templates and possibly some other tools useful for web (but also other types of apps), that are not dependent on platform (ex. `nodejs`/`java`). I don't see reason why this has to be 100% platform specific. If there's routing and generic request/response object, there can be implementation for example both for `node express` or for example `java servlets` with correct mapping and wrappers. Has anyone tried to do that yet? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Ktor](https://ktor.io).

Comment: I know about ktor. Client is multiplatform, but as far as I know, server side is always java.

Comment: Yes, [but](https://ktor.io/quickstart/index.html): "Currently, JVM client and server scenarios are supported, as well as JavaScript, iOS and Android clients, and **we are working on bringing server facilities to native environments**, and client facilities to other native targets."

Comment: Ye fair enough, I was actively looking for that, but didn't. Cheers